# Overwriting django Integer choices output in graphene

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I'm working with graphene and graphene-django and I have a problem with a IntegerField with choices. graphene create an Enum and the output is "A_1" if the value is 1; "A_2" if the value is 2 and so on. Example:

```
# model
class Foo(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)))

# query

query {
    foo {
       score
    }
}

# response 

{
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "source": "A_1"
    }
  }
}
```

How I can overwrite this output?

(ps: I've copied the question from an old post but there is no any proper comment for today, because it is from 4,5 years ago. I've had exactly the same problem today)
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Actually i've found the proper answer in the graphene documents,

We should add a row like that `convert_choices_to_enum = False` under the node class in schema mutation to disable this automatic conversion.

The exact link for the document page is https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_score(enum_output):
    return enum_output.split('_')[1]

####
{
    "data": {
    "foo": {
        "source": get_score("A_1")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.